# Is this luggage likely to be considered oversized as checked baggage?

Tags: uk, luggage, airlines, check-in

I've recently purchased and fitted a container for a costume I plan to take to conventions abroad.

It's a cube shaped flight case measuring 530 x 530 x 530 mm. I added that up, and god damn it, it comes to 159 linear cm (63 linear inches)! So 1 cm over the limit for many airlines.

(I also have bolted on wheels, feet, and an extendible handle, but these can be removed if necessary. With them it comes to about 163 linear cm.)

Am I likely to get stung with oversized baggage for for being 1 cm over the limit? And would it be prudent for me to remove the accessories before checking in/bag drop?

Weight isn't an issue, the thing it's carrying is very light, so it will weigh <20kg when full.

Although I am not concerned about my next trip to Berlin from Manchester (easyJet appear to have a very generous hold luggage size allowance, much larger than I need), I might plan on taking them to other conventions, perhaps to the US where the oversized charges would be higher.

Comment: Maybe a useful question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47736/is-it-safe-to-knowingly-buy-an-oversized-67-inch-suitcase-are-size-limits-enf

Comment: @pnuts are you saying his chances are excellent to have to pay oversized? or to not have to pay oversized?

Comment: I'd ask why this question was too broad, and what could be done to improve it, but after the awful experience I had with workplace.SE (long story short, they accused me of something I vehemently deny), I don't want to risk being put through that again (even though I'm sure you have a much clearer reason than they did).